# How to set environment variables on MacOS using a GUI?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, gui

I'm trying to provide instructions to several people on how to set an environment variable in MacOS.

I want the variable to be permanent, not require reboot, and it must work for all gui applications.

Unfortunately, any solution that requires vim or even nano isn't going to fly.

How exactly can this be done only using a gui application? (And the simpler the better)

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? I suspect there might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. User-set environment variables affecting GUI apps has never really been a thing on macOS. There have been obscure, poorly-supported hacks to do this that have changed over time, and never really caught on. You probably need a different, macOS-savvy, way to accomplish your underlying goal.

Comment: Indeed I can. I'm working on a Reaper project with several people across Linux, Windows, and MacOS. This Reaper project uses a plugin for rendering soundfonts. The plugin uses an environment variable for managing the soundfont library path. We have Linux and Windows working just fine, as it's quite easy to set environment variables in those operating systems. MacOS can't do it?

Comment: The Mac way to do this is for user-controllable settings to be editable via the app's own GUI, often via a "Preferences" window. Did you run the macOS version of Reaper yourself and look to see if this is already something in the GUI? I tried it out and it seems to have an extensive preferences window, including settings for its plugins and various paths for things.

Comment: Assuming you keep these soundfonts in the proper place, then `/Library/Audio/Soundfonts/`  **is** en environment variable ie, a repeatable path not dependant on hard drive name. I don't use Reaper, but I'm surprised that isn't there as a default.

Comment: This environment variable is used by the *plugin* not *Reaper*. The plugin doesn't provide a way to edit OS level environment variables, as all OSes generally provide a sane method for doing this. I would love to use ````/Library/Audio/Soundfonts/```` as the path for the plugin, but in order to do so, I must tell the plugin what path to use. And the plugin reads that path from an environment variable. The plugin has no other way to get the library path.

Comment: As making custom environment variables on Mac is just not done, are you absolutely certain that is the method the plugin requires, on Mac? It makes no sense to me as a Mac user that you would have to invent some $PATH stored outside the app/plugin in order to access a known location.

Comment: Yes I am 100% certain, as I spoke with the plugin dev directly. PATH doesn't have to be changed, the environment variable in question is SFZ_PATH. Again, the plugin works perfectly on both Windows and Linux, as long as that environment variable is set correctly. It sounds like MacOS is missing a crucial OS level feature if it can't do this. What about using ````launchctl````?

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in way to do this in the GUI, but you could take a look at https://github.com/hschmidt/EnvPane

Comment: It sounds to me more like the plugin dev doesn't know how macOS works. Expecting similar behaviours cross-platform really isn't the way to go. Anyway, as your information is not really forthcoming & remains minimal, I'm not sure how we can help further. Insisting macOS **should** do this just to satisfy one plugin isn't really a solution.

Comment: Doesn't setting in `/etc/profile` some `export` commands work in MacOS?

Comment: Honestly it is astonishing that a supposedly POSIX compliant OS lacks a feature that has been present in Unix since 1979.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you so much for this! This looks like exactly what is needed here.

Comment: @Tetsujin What information is needed that I haven't provided yet? I'm happy to provide any additional needed information. I'm not a developer, but I don't think it's too far off base to assume that a *nix derived OS would include the most basic, rudimentary feature that every other single *nix OS supports. It's not just related to a single plugin, a bit of googling will reveal pages and pages of forum posts from developers complaining about this problem. A better question is: why did Apple feel the need to make the distinction between command line and gui applications with respect to env vars?

Comment: You're still making this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) You haven't told us any detail - not even the name of the plugin, what path it actually asks for, where & how, what format it expects this variable - no actual detail at all, just insistence that it *must* be done this way & no other. It's not like I'm new to this. I've been using sequencers since the early 80s, a decade before they could even do audio, worked for one of the major mfrs & beta-tested for most of the others across 20 years & have never come up against this 'seemingly insurmountable' issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have set up a way to do this, with documentation text files. However, it does require use of nano if the user wants to decide what environment variables to set. If you supply that, then the user doesn't have to use nano. BUT, the process is tricky with lots of gotchas to install it, so even then it is probably too much for your users.  But I'd like to make it available to anyone that wants it. Since I can't attach a file here, I guess I'll put all the file contents into code blocks below.  The method used is to create a .plist file that MacOS loads at startup, and that file has bash code that reads a text file provided in the user's home directory containing environment variables to be set.

Here is the contents of the environment.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.startup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>while read LINE; do NAME=${LINE%%=*}; VALUE=${LINE#*=}; eval launchctl setenv $NAME &quot;$VALUE&quot;; done &lt;~/environment.txt; echo &quot;environment.plist ran on $(date)&quot; &gt;&gt; ~/environment.plist.log</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is a sample environment.txt file to be placed in the user's home directory to set some environment variables:

```
LOCAL_ROOT=/Users/$USER/archive
SOFTWARE_ROOT=$LOCAL_ROOT/PKGS
REPO_DIR=$SOFTWARE_ROOT/repositories
RSOURCEPATH=$REPO_DIR/rscripts/libraries
```

Here is my environment.readme.txt file to accompany environment.txt in the user's home directory:

```
This file accompanies file environment.txt.

PLACE GLOBAL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES IN ~/environment.txt   !!!!

Full instructions describing environment.txt can be found in the file:
    environment.plist.readme.txt
which should be in the directory ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Edit environment.txt to set the environment variables that you want.  You can
edit the file with any text editor, e.g. nano:
    nano ~/environment.txt
In nano, use the arrow keys to move around, the backspace key to delete text,
and use control/x followed by a Y and enter to exit and save the changes. Also,
follow the steps in environment.plist.readme.txt to check the file for correct
line endings and fix them if necessary.

PLACE GLOBAL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES IN ~/environment.txt   !!!!
THEY CAN USE OTHER PRE-EXISTING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE VALUES IN THEM !!!!
FOR EXAMPLE: XXX=/Users/$USER/xxx

LOG OUT AND LOG BACK IN FOR THE CHANGES TO TAKE EFFECT!
```

Finally, here is the environment.plist.readme.txt file with the detailed instructions for use:

```
PLACE GLOBAL ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES IN ~/environment.txt   !!!!

This accompanies file environment.plist (for Mac computers running MacOS) that
sets global environment variables so that they can be seen by apps started via a
mouse click on an icon.  (Environment variables set in a shell profile file
cannot be seen by apps started that way).

The environment.plist file should load and run automatically whenever you boot
your Mac.

To use the environment.plist file, while logged in as your username and not as
root user, copy this file and environment.plist to your directory named:
    ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then set the correct file permissions with:
    chmod u+rw,g+r,o+r ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
Also, make sure the file hasn't been quarantined by an anti-virus program or
had extended attributes attached to it that might interfere with its loading,
by using the command:
    ls -l
You should see permissions for the file as -rw-r--r-- and if an @ occurs after
this, it means the file has extended attributes, which you can view with:
    xattr ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
The attribute com.apple.quarantine will definitely prevent the file from loading
and other attributes might also block it.  You can remove an attribute with:
    xattr -d <attribute name> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
Then test the .plist file for correctness with the command:
    plutil ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist

Next, copy environment.txt and environment.readme.txt to your ~ (home) directory
and edit environment.txt to set the global environment variables you desire.
(The sample environment.txt file has some sample settings). You can use existing
environment variables such as USER as part of your environment variable
definitions in environment.txt, e.g. "XXX=/Users/$USER/xxx", and you can use
your new environment variables in subsequent environment variable definitions in
the file.

For the next step, you need to know your user id uid number, which you can find
with this command:
    id
Typically on a Mac the uid often is 501.  Using the uid, test the .plist and
.txt files with these commands:
    launchctl bootout gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
    launchctl enable user/501/~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
    launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist

Each time environment.plist runs, it writes a line at the end of a log file
showing the date it ran.  Examine that file to see if it has a new entry, using
this command:
    cat ~/environment.plist.log
Each time you log in, and each time you run the three launchctl commands above,
a new line should be added to the log file, so you should see one line in the
file after running the above launchctl commands.

At this point, logging out and back in should cause the environment.plist file
to run and read the environment.txt file and assign those environment variables.
You should see them in any program you start yourself, but they won't show up in
any program started by MacOS automatically at login (and I don't know how to fix
that problem).

If everything works well, skip the remainder of this document, but if not, read
on and you might be able to fix the problem.

It is important that the environment.txt file have only a newline (\n) as line
end, not \r\n or only \r. If you created it with the nano editor, it should be
okay. To find out what the line endings are, you can use this command:
    hexdump ~/environment.txt | less
Look through the hex bytes to find 0a (\n), 0d (\r), or 0d followed by 0a. It
should occur at the end of each line (each hex byte XX corresponds to one
character in the file) and particularly after the last line. Use the space bar
to scroll through the bytes and q to quit out of the 'less' program. If you find
only a 0d and no 0a, fix the file like this:
    tr '\r' '\n' ~/environment.txt >env.txt
    mv env.txt environment.txt
If you find 0d followed by 0a, fix the file like this:
    tr -d '\r' ~/environment.txt >env.txt
    mv env.txt environment.txt

If the log file ~/environment.plist.log doesn't exist or doesn't have a new line
at the end of the file showing the date you ran the launchctl commands above,
then something is wrong, which is frequently the case. You need to go back and
check all the above steps and recheck the file contents, owner, and permissions
carefully and try the launchctl commands a second time.  If it still isn't
adding a new entry to the log file when you run those commands, then restarting
your computer might fix the problem.  Do that and try again.  Otherwise, I don't
know what else to try.

If the log file looks okay, test to see if your environment variables have been
set by exiting the Terminal application completely, then restarting it, and
using this command:
    echo $<ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME>
Use the name of one of your environment variables, e.g. 'echo $LOCAL_ROOT'
You should see the VALUE you assigned to that environment variable printed out.
The value will be empty if you have not exited and restarted your terminal
console app after running the launchctl commands.

Next, log out and log back in to your computer and go into the Terminal app and
do the above 'echo' command again. If it doesn't print out the expected
environment variable value, this is probably because Terminal was started by
MacOS automatically when you logged in.  Programs that start automatically will
not have access to the environment variables.  Only programs that you start
yourself will have access.  Try exiting the terminal app and restarting it, then
check the environment variable again.  If it still isn't okay, run through
everything one more time to see if you can get it working, and if not, I don't
have any other ideas to recommend.

Finally, once you see that the 'echo' command shows an environment variable
value, double-check that the variable is accessible from an app started with a
mouse-clicked-icon. If you have RStudio or R installed, start that app with the
mouse. Then, at the console prompt, type the command:
    Sys.getenv("<ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME>")
It should show the value of the environment variable with that name.  E.g.:
    Sys.getenv("LOCAL_ROOT")

CAUTION: If you allow MacOS to restore your apps and windows when you log in, or
if you specify certain apps to be started automatically at login using System
Preferences, Users and Groups, Login Items, those automatically started apps
will not see the new environment variables.  The solution is to close and
re-open any app that was started automatically at login and needs to use those
environment variables.

Theory of operation: When a user logs in, MacOS locates .plist files in folder
~/Library/LaunchAgents and parses them and executes commands in them. The
accompanying plist file, environment.plist, has commands to run a bash shell
subcommand that reads file ~/environment.txt and parses it as a series of
NAME=VALUE lines, then calls 'launchctl setenv' to set NAME as a global
environment variable with value VALUE, and finally, it writes the date to the
end of the log file. All that is accomplished with one long BASH command in the
.plist file, shown here broken into five lines but present in a single LONG line
in the .plist file:
    while read LINE; do NAME=${LINE%%=*}; VALUE=${LINE#*=};
    eval launchctl setenv $NAME &quot;$VALUE&quot;;
    eval export $NAME=&quot;$VALUE&quot;;
    done &lt;~/environment.txt;
    echo &quot;environment.plist ran on $(date)&quot; &gt;&gt; ~/environment.plist.log

Note that semicolons separate BASH commands on one line, &quot; is translated
into the character " (quote), and &lt; is translated into the character < (less
than), and &gt; is translated into the character > (greater than) by the .plist
parser.  The .plist file must have permissions u+rw,g+r,o+r and be owned by the
home directory user and not have a quarantine extended attribute in order for it
to be loaded by MacOS automatically when you log in.
```

Comment: Replace ``VALUE=${LINE/*=/}`` with ``VALUE=${LINE#*=}`` for better accuracy.
I was using a special ``VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC=whatever | source $MYVIMRC'`` command which was not correctly parsed.

Comment: Thanks, Damien. I thought you were missing a `/` but I'm just reading the bash parameter expansion section more carefully and learned about the `parameter#` and `parameter%%` forms of substitution. I think that the NAME= portion is better written as NAME=${LINE%%=*} don't you think? I'll adjust my code above for these changes.

Comment: Under which license can these files be used and distributed?

Comment: No license needed, just use it.

Comment: I'm currently having a problem.  After the last macOS update, these are no longer working, and I don't know why.  They aren't auto-loading.  When I manually run them with launchctl, it works fine, but when I reboot, the environment variables aren't there.  If anybody has more suggestions beyond what is shown in the plist readme file above, please chime in.